# How to add "product" to the cart programatically in Sylius

Tags: sylius

Given current cart and the variant id, how to add this variant to the cart programatically (without additional HTTP requests)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find variant you want to add:

```
$variant = $this->container->get('sylius.repository.product_variant')->findOneById(123);
```

Create new order item

```
$orderItem = $this->container->get('sylius.factory.order_item')->createNew();
```

Set variant to order item entity

```
$orderItem->setVariant($variant);
```

Modify order item quantity (you have to do it even with 1 unit, otherwise there will be error that you cannot add order item in 0 quantity)

```
$this->container->get('sylius.order_item_quantity_modifier')->modify($orderItem, 3);
```

Add order item to order

```
$order->addItem($orderItem);
```

Finally trigger order processors (taxes, promotions etc..)

```
$this->container->get('sylius.order_processing.order_processor')->process($order);
```